# How does a react action have access to dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

In my react project I have an actions file that looks like this:

```
const startLoad = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: CONTENT_LOAD,
  });
};

// Get all content
export const getContents = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(startLoad());
  // some more code...
};
```

So in this example, I know that dispatch is coming from the `middleware` and `getContents` has access to it because it was mapped using `mapDispatchToProps`. So I am assuming when `getContents` is called, its really called like this -> `dispatch(getContents)` but can this be replicated in plain JavaScript so I can see what is really going on? If I am wrong about why `getContents` has access to `dispatch` please let me know.

For example, how is`startLoad` able to use `dispatch` just because `dispatch` called `startLoad`? I have noticed that it will also work if I call it like this: `dispatch(startLoad(dispatch));`.

Passing dispatch in to `startLoad` actually makes more sense to me so I don't get why that isn't required.

**Edit: this is the closest example I could come up with on my own.**

```
const fun = () => (fun2) => {
  fun2();
}

const fun2 = () => {
  console.log('hello');
}

fun()(fun2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I am assuming when getContents is called, its really called like
> this -> dispatch(getContents) but can this be replicated in plain
> JavaScript so I can see what is really going on? If I am wrong about
> why getContents has access to dispatch please let me know.

[redux-thunk has quite simple implementation](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js)

```js
function createThunkMiddleware(extraArgument) {
  return ({ dispatch, getState }) => (next) => (action) => {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
      return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument);
    }

    return next(action);
  };
}
```

As you can see it checks if action is a function.

*And bonus, if you like you can get the whole state and extra argument in params following dispatch*

> For example, how isstartLoad able to use dispatch just because
> dispatch called startLoad? I have noticed that it will also work if I
> call it like this: dispatch(startLoad(dispatch));.

It looks like middleware also handles above case.